# Finding the sum of same numbers in an array

Tags: java

I want to sum same numbers in an array. Output is:

```
20
20
20
60
```

But I want output:

```
30 60
```

Here is my code:

```
int sum = 0;
int array[] = {10, 10, 10, 20, 30, 30};

for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int k = i + 1; k < array.length; k++) {
        if(i != k && array[i] == array[k]) {
            sum = array[i] + array[k];

            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your output?

Comment: 10+10+10=30 30+30=60

Comment: Sorry @asdf, still not clear. Can you further explain? Either your input or output doesn't seem correct.

Comment: This can be easily done by writing exactly what you personally would do if you have this task? Would you ignore the former `sum` value or would print it before checking that there aren't any other equal numbers? Just take a piece of paper, write down what you would do and then translate that into Java.

Comment: @kartikmaji The title says it all "sum equal numbers". His input and the expected output is ok (if he doesn't care about unique numbers).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` to do this like so:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> sums = new HashMap<>();    

int[] arr = {10,10,10,20,30,30};
for(int i=0,n=arr.length;i<n;i++){
    sums.put(arr[i], sums.get(arr[i])==null?arr[i]:sums.get(arr[i])+arr[i]);
}
```

This will group each of the unique values in your `Array` with their respective sums.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to this:

### We all love Java8 <3

```
String result = Stream.of(3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2).
            collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity())).
            entrySet().stream().
                map(e->e.getKey() * e.getValue().size()).
                collect(StringBuilder::new, (s, i)->s.append(i).append(", "), (a, b)->a.append(b)).
                    toString();
```

Builds a table listing all integers with the same value, translates that into the sums of equal numbers and collects those into a `StringBuilder`

### Using a table

```
int[] test = new int[]{3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2};

Map<Integer, Integer> ints = new HashMap<>();
for(int i : test)
    ints.put(i, ints.getOrDefault(i, 0) + i);

System.out.println(ints.toString());
```

This code simply builds a table containing each integer, and it's respective count multiplied by that integer.

### Naive approach

Just for the sake of completeness:

```
int[] test = new int[]{3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2};
boolean[] flags = new boolean[test.length];

for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
{
    //ignore already processed items
    if(flags[i])
        continue;

    flags[i] = true;

    //sum up and mark processed elements as processed
    int tmp = test[i];
    for(int j = i + 1; j < test.length; j++)
        if(test[j] == test[i]) {
            flags[j] = true;
            tmp += test[i];
        }

    System.out.print(tmp + " ");
}
```

This code works by starting with the first element, finds all equal values, marks those as visited (to avoid duplication - `flags`), prints their sum and continues with the next unprocessed element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using Java 8's `stream()`, e.g:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] array = {10, 10, 10, 20, 30, 30};
    Map<Integer, Long> mappings = 
            Arrays.stream(array)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
    for(Integer key : mappings.keySet()){
        if(mappings.get(key) > 1){
            System.out.println(key * mappings.get(key));
        }
    }

}
```